# Past Indefinite or Past Continuous?

Tags: past-tense, progressive-aspect, past-continuous

I have a simple at first sight question, but it seems confusing for some of my collegues. There is the sentence, where we need to insert Past Simple or Past Continuous, please help to fill these gaps

> Scott and his friends were playing a game of volleyball on the beach. The boys [ **threw** / **were throwing** ]  the ball over the girl's heads into the sea and the girls [ **laughed** / **were laughing** ]

Comment: I think both will work here (and in quite a few different combinations). The ELL community may be able to say what's likely to be required in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence

> Scott and his friends were playing a game of volleyball on the beach. The boys [ threw / were throwing ] the ball over the girl's heads into the sea and the girls [ laughed / were laughing ]

It would depend if the boys only threw the ball once or continuously

> The boys *threw* the ball over the girl's heads into the sea *(sounds like one time)*
>   The boys *were throwing* the ball over the girl's heads into the sea *(more than once)*

and as a the result

> and the girls *laughed*.

is appropriate for either scenario.

To say

> the girls *were laughing*.

sounds like they were laughing irregardless of the boys throwing a ball.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence describes the first one. Past continuous is used to describe parallel actions.

" The boys were throwing the ball over the girl's heads into the sea and the girls were laughing " seems way more appropriate in this case than past simple that describes a series of completed actions in the past.

[Reference](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html)